# np.insert() -1 as the position of an element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert

I am playing with the NumPy library and there is a behaviour that I do not understand:

I defined a simple vector Y:

```
Y = np.array([6,7,8],dtype = np.int16)
```

Then, I tried to add an additional element at the end of the array using the `np.insert()`  method. I specified the position to be at -1:

```
Z = np.insert(Y,(-1),(19))
```

My element was inserted not on the last, but on the penultimate position:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZCc.png)

Could somebody explain my why this element was not inserted at the end of my array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative indexes are calculated using `len(l) + i` (with `l` being the object and `i` being the negative index).

For example, with a list `x = [1, 2, 3, 4]` the index -2 is calculated as 4-2 = 2, so `x[-2]` returns 3

In this example, the index -1 is calculated as index 2

Therefore, 19 is inserted at index 2, the penultimate position. To fix this, use `Z = np.insert(Y, len(Y), 19)`.

PS - this is the same with `list.insert`, not just with numpy arrays

Edit (suggested by Homer512): `np.append` may be easier than `np.insert` if you want to add to the end of an array: `Z = np.append(Y, 19)`

Comment: Good explanation. I suggest directing users to ```np.append``` instead

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer with this method!

Comment: `np.insert(x,1,10)` places the `10` **before** the `x[1]` element.  `x[-1]` is the last element

Comment: Which is why I suggested `np.insert(Y, len(Y), 19)`